# Accessing network shares

Tags: 12.04, networking, fstab

I'm looking for some help on how to connect and mount network shares on my current install of 12.04. The fileserver shares that I'm trying to access are on a Solaris 11 system using ZFS. Just wondering what I need to change/add to the fstab in order to be able to access them? I can access them fine from windows by just mapping them as \hostname\sharename.

Am I missing something or do I have to install an extra packages?

Comment: Do you access the shares via smb on windows? If so, do the same on linux -- test with nautilus->Goto->Location 'smb://hostname/sharename'...

Comment: All working now thanks, turns out that I'd forgotten to install smbfs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, install `zfs-fuse`: `sudo apt-get install zfs-fuse`
After that actually the zfs-fuse init script will mount it for you.
Manually you can issue: `sudo zfs mount -a`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, even after installing fuse and attempting to mount them with the script, I still can't see or access any of the shares or see the machine.

Comment: On Solaris side it is everything OK? I assumed that you are familiar with ZFS... Read this: http://drwetter.eu/blog/zfs_under_linux.en.html

Comment: Yeah everything is okay on the Solaris box, all pools are online and have been scrubbed with no errors detected. I've just checked and they're also accessible from mac and windows machines currently, just not linux.